# jQuery Sticky Sidebar failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

First of all *I did not write this code.* I found it on somebody else's website and I want to learn from it by trying it out myself. However I can't make it work. I've googled for the code in case it's a jQuery plugin that's freely available or anything, but I can't find it anywhere on the web.

I have my sidebar (with id #sidebar) and have given it the class "sticky", I've included jQuery at the top of the page, and I've put this code in place in the head:

```
<!-- Floating sidebar jQuery --> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var Sticky = function( $obj, opts ){

               $(window).scroll( 
                  function(e){
                     Sticky.onScroll(e, $obj, opts );
                  });

            }
            Sticky.onScroll = function( e, $o, opts ){

               var iScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
               var sClass = "sticky";

               //set original data
               if( !$o.data(sClass) ){
                  $o.data(sClass, {css:{position:$o.css('position'),top:$o.css('top')}, offset:$o.offset()} );
               }
               var oOrig = $o.data(sClass);
               var bIsSticky = $o.hasClass(sClass);

               if( iScrollTop > oOrig.offset.top && !bIsSticky ){
                  $o.css({position:'fixed',top:0}).addClass(sClass);
               }else if(iScrollTop < oOrig.offset.top && bIsSticky){
                  $o.css(oOrig.css).removeClass(sClass);
               }   

            }

            Sticky( $('#sidebar') );

        </script>
```

As you can see, the final JS line `Sticky( $('#sidebar') );` fires on the #sidebar element. However, when you scroll down, this error is written to Chrome's log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Firebug is a bit more verbose, and says:

> oOrig is undefined: `if( iScrollTop >
>   oOrig.offset.top && !bIsSticky ){`

I'm trying my best to understand this but can somebody help me see why it's not working?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: What is the output if you put `console.log($o.data(sClass));` before `var oOrig = $o.data(sClass);`? I cannot see an error in the code. Add some `log` calls and check the contents of the variables. Also check, whether the code inside `if( !$o.data(sClass) )` statement is  executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, new answer...Thanks felix

wrap the function call in a ready function.

```
$(function() {
    Sticky($('#sidebar'));
});
```

The dom is most likely not ready when you call `Sticky($('#sidebar'))` so when .data is used to set data on `$o` it actual does nothing:

```
$o.data(sClass, {css:{position:$o.css('position'),top:$o.css('top')}, offset:$o.offset()} );].
```

So when it gets the data on line:

```
var oOrig = $o.data(sClass);
```

it cannot actualy get the data.

This is because the dom elements are not ready to be manipulated because the dom is not ready yet.

### OLD ANSWER (NOT RIGHT!)

$.offset is a function.

The problem in the line:

```
if( iScrollTop > oOrig.offset.top && !bIsSticky ){
```

is that: `oOrig.offset` is a function, not a variable. So `oOrig.offset.top` is not valid. Simply call the function and it will return a variable with the top property which you can access:

```
if( iScrollTop > oOrig.offset().top && !bIsSticky ){
```

Explination:

`oOrig.offset` is a reference to a function (the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function in jquery).

You must call the function to access the `.top` property.

Comment: I'm afraid that still triggers the same error, the Console just gives the same message but with a couple of brackets after offset! :(

EDIT: Chrome now says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'offset' of undefined"

Comment: It still says that oOrig is undefined.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Why those upvotes? `offset` is not a function on `oOrig`. If you look closely, then `oOrig` is the object that is stored in `$o.data(sClass)` which is `{css:{position:$o.css('position'),top:$o.css('top')}, offset:$o.offset()}`. And even if it was a function, then it would throw another error and *not* that *`oOrig` is undefined*.

Comment: @Bob: in the `if` statement you're talking about, `oOrig.offset` actually _is_ a variable. `oOrig` comes from `.data()`, so it should be a plain old object with 3 properties, `css`, `top`, and `offset`. Look at the line immediately below the `//set original data` comment. It looks to me like the problem is that the `$o.data(sClass, {/*...*/})` isn't happening correctly.

Comment: @Bob Fincheimer: Can happen ;) I hope you are not offended by the first two sentences of my previous comment. I just wondered why people so quickly up-vote answers that sound reasonable without verifying them.

Comment: Glad we've got that sorted, but, uh - can anyone help out any further? I'm really trying my best to understand all this. Y'know, we've all got to start somewhere...

Comment: This could be indeed the problem, good idea! Actually by reading the question, it should be clear: *I've put this code in place in the head*. +1 good catch!

Comment: Hooray! Thanks Bob, that solved the problem. Cheers for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using seems overly complicated. I wrote a tutorial on how to achieve this that should be much easier to implement and less error prone.

http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/